# How can I tell if a mutual fund is open-ended

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds

I have restrictions on what type of securities I may buy and sell. However, I'm free to trade open-ended mutual funds. I looked at the [Investopida definition](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/open-endfund.asp), and I see that anything that I can freely buy more of is open. This leads me to a few questions. First, isn't any fund that I do not own and can purchase open? Second, how can I tell if a fund that I do own is still open?

Edit: I am in the US if it matters.

Comment: Is this in the US, UK or somewhere else? Different countries may have different rules. For example, I'm in Canada.

Comment: @JBKing In US, but I would think that being an open-ended fund would be the same in any country

Answer (score 1):

Open-end funds in the US would generally have a 5 letter ticker and be registered under the ["Investment Company Act"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investment_Company_Act_of_1940) that makes them companies unto themselves with varying amounts of shares. There can be share classes for various open-end funds with varying fees and minimums and I doubt that every country has the same details as the ICA which is what governs funds in the US.

Most big ["fund families"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mutual-fund_families_in_the_United_States) will have a variety of open-end funds though lots of discount brokerage firms may be known as "fund supermarkets" because of their selection of funds outside of a family, e.g. Schwab would be more of a supermarket as it was originally known more for being a brokerage firm while Vanguard or Fidelity would be a couple of fund families though both do have brokerage arms. This would be the classic way to buy the funds and sites like [Morningstar](http://www.morningstar.com/) can provide research on funds if you want such a reference.

There can be other funds that will trade on exchanges known as "Closed-End Funds" or "Exchange-Traded Funds" where the former have fixed number of shares and a fixed liquidation date while the latter can have flexible number of shares but can be either "Unit Investment Trust" or a mutual fund structure I believe as Vanguard's ETFs do use an open-end fund structure to some degree.